# PHP, MySQL - Return which value was used when input is an array?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm running a PDO query, something like:

```
$inputArr = array(val1, val2, val3, ...);

$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($inputArr) - 1) . '?';

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name, type, level
                      FROM table 
                      WHERE name IN ($qMarks)");

$stmt->execute($inputArr);

... parse the rows that have been returned
```

And this works exactly as expected, no hang-ups or anything.

My problem is that I need to know which value from `$inputArr` was used to get each row returned.

I've tried

```
WHERE name IN ($qMarks) AS inputVal
```

and

```
WHERE name IN ($qMarks AS inputVal)
```

but those crash the query.

How can I determine which input array value was used to return each row in the output?

**EDIT 1**

Yes, I understand that the input search value would be `name`, for this particular case, but the query above is only for demonstration purposes of how I am putting the search values into the query.

The actual is much more complex, and returns any `name` value with is *close* (but not always identical).

Comment: Umm..  When you fetch the row wouldn't it be in `$row['name']` since that matched something in `$qMarks` ???

Comment: @AbraCadaver it isn't that simple. The actual query uses a custom function to return name values that are *close*, but not always identical, and also has two `LEFT JOIN` in it. This is just for demonstration sake of how I am putting the search values into the query.

Comment: Yeah, that's normally useful information up front.

Comment: @Birrel I read this comment after having posted my answer. We would have to know a bit more about your SQL statement in order to give you a better answer. I'd say there are 2 main ways of finding a solution to this. 1 through PHP by analysing the output, and another with SQL by analysing the input, but we can't be sure if either of them would work because we can't analyse your specific case without a better notion of what we are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

The `AS` keyword is not going to work as you expect it. It's mainly used for aliasing subqueries. You can't (to my knowledge) use it in a `WHERE` clause.

The scenario you've outlined should have the 'name' in `$row['name']`. If it was a different variable that you wanted to see, you'd simply add it in your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Even with subqueries and joins, you should still be able to output what was matched in the `SELECT` clause. Perhaps if you posted a query closer to what is going on, we might be able to get a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Great question, and simple answer:

The `WHERE name IN $qMarks)");` part of your code is only obtaining the values in your database that are matching your array, so what you can do is see which values of `name` are present in the row you fetched. For example:

```
$rows_fetched = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCHASSOC);

$inputArray = array();

foreach($rows_fetched as $value)
{
  $inputArray[] = $value['name'];
}

print_r($inputArray);//printing the results
```

Now you have the array `$inputArray` with all the values used to return each row in the output. Let me know if that worked for you!